# JDBC Select from 2 columns within the same table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I've been having hard times finding the appropriate syntax for a prepared statement.

This is what I currently have:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1" + "WHERE Col1="+val1+ "AND Col2="+val2;
```

Can you please tell me what the actual syntax is, as I keep getting an SQL syntax error?
Thanks :)

Comment: No space between table_name and where. And also if col1 and col2 are varchar then single quotes before and after val1 and val2

Comment: also between val1 and AND

Comment: "SELECT * FROM TABLE1  WHERE  Col1= '"+val1+ "'  AND Col2 = '"+val2+" ' ";

Comment: why not prepared query: `"select * from TABLE1 where col1 = ? and col2 = ?"`?

Comment: From my best knowledge this is the straight way to any type of sql-injections. Better write select as 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Col1=? and Col2=?` and use prepareStatement

Answer (score 2):

There is no space between your table name and where clause.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Col1="+val1+ " AND Col2="+val2;
```

And if `Col1` and `COl2` are varchar then single quotes before and after val1 and val2.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Col1='"+val1+ "' AND Col2='"+val2+"'";
```

And better using parameters instead of giving values directly. It helps prevent SQL Injection attacks

Comment: you really advise assigning parameters by string concatenation?